# Each word timeStamp Speech Api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech

There's some way to get time when user say each word?

```
recognition.onsoundstart   = function(event){
    console.log("onsoundstart");
}
```

And

```
recognition.onspeechstart = function(event){
    console.log("onspeechstart");
}
```

give me result only on first word.
The results they wish to [[word], [timeStamp]]: [["Hi"], [212321]], [["my"], [212331]], [["name], [212341]], [["is"], [212351]], [["Bond"], [212361]]

Comment: Your question is also very poorly worded. You might wish to edit it and correct your mistakes to avoid it being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the user speaks with a pause between each word, that would work. The event starts and ends when the user speaks into the microphone, and there's a grace period until the recording ends to help slow speakers.

Comment: so there's no technical way to find that time?